# codeigniter: ion auth with shopping cart

Tags: codeigniter, cart

I am integrating ion auth with the codeigniter cart, both are working independently however if I have items in my cart then I login, I lose the cart items.

Guess this is session related, I have scanned the login scripts and doesnt seem to be ended the session and starting a new one, so I am a bit lost.

Fairly new to codeigniter, so if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great?

Thanks,

Martyn

Answer (score 0):

Ion auth and the Codeigniter cart class both use Codeigniter sessions, and not native PHP sessions. You are probably using an older version of Ion auth which clears the Codeigniter session on login. Try using the latest version: [Ion Auth on github.](http://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth) 
Also, the codeigniter cookie is limited to 4kB, less with encryption, so consider using PHP native session for your cart class.